# Get form data using get method in python webapp2

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am using python to develop a web app, and I want to get data from my form in the getmethod. How do I do this? Below is my code:

```
class RedirectPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.write('<html><body><h1> TJust a trial </h1>')
        self.response.write("""Enter your comment:
        <form method = "get" name = "frm">
        <input type = "textarea" id = "forms" name ="answered" value = "this"></input>
        <input type = "textarea" name ="unanswered" value = "this"></input>
        <input type = "textarea" name ="correct" value = "this"></input>
        <input type = "textarea" name ="wrong" value = "this"></input>
        <input type="submit"></input>
        </form><script type="text/javascript">
        var id = ""+window.location.hash;
        var details= id.substring(1,id.length);
        var user_details = new Array();
        user_details = details.split("gc");
        var answered = user_details[0];
        var unanswered = user_details[1];
        var correct = user_details[2];
        var wrong = user_details[3];
        document.frm.answered.value = answered;
        document.frm.unanswered.value = unanswered;
        document.frm.correct.value = correct;
        document.frm.wrong.value = wrong;
        </script>"""
        )
```

Now, from the code above, how do I get like the value in `name="correct"`. I do not want to use the post method because I want the page to redirect after executing the code above.

Comment: Please don't write code like this. We have template languages for a reason. You've even tagged your question with "Jinja", but you don't actually seem to be using it.

Comment: yep.. the code is just a fragment of my code... ur comment does nt ans my question. i used template bt in this part of my code, i want to get d values frm my form.. hw do i do that pls

Comment: you create a post handler and read the data in from the POST dictionary of values.

Comment: can u give a sample code pleaase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably using Webapp2 in GAE. So this should work:

The basic setup is a POST handler that receives the POST data:

```
class MyHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        name = self.request.get('name')
```

If you have a value named "name" in the form you are submitting it's contents will be assigned to the variable "`name`".

Likewise:

```
# <input name="name" type="text" />
name = self.request.get("name")

# <input name="subscribe" type="checkbox" value="yes" />
subscribe_to_newsletter = self.request.get("subscribe", default_value="no")

# <select name="favorite_foods" multiple="true">...</select>
favorite_foods = self.request.get("favorite_foods", allow_multiple=True)
```

More here: http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/request.html